# extension method for List<T> with both constraints class and struct

Tags: c#, .net

I want to write extension for `List<MyClass>` and `List<int>`, `List<string>`, and other types.

I tried to write this code:

```
public static int MyMethod<T>(this List<T> list) where T : struct  where T : class
{
    int result = //do something
    return result;
}
```

Comment: simply omit the constraint, as struct + class = everything. Apart from this you can add multiple constraints with a single comma: `where T: class, new()`.

Comment: The question is: what you don't want? What is `do something` btw?

Comment: The compiler doesn't let you add both constraints, classes and structs.  _"Cannot specify both reference and value constraint"_ Such a constraint would be superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there´s no type that is neither a class nor a struct, applying both constraints to your member is redundant. Thus you can simply omit it completely, making your method work on *any* `T`.

```
public static int MyMethod<T>(this List<T> list)
{
    int result = //do something
    return result;
}
```

Apart from this you can of course add multiple constraints to a method, e.g. this:

```
public void DoSomething<T>() where T: class, new() { /* ... */ }
```

which would make this method exist for reference-types with a parameterless constructor.

EDIT: when you have some specific types in mind, you should consider to create two methods instead, as you can´t do much for both integers and strings. So make two methods:

```
public static int MyMethodForInt(this List<string> list)
{
    int result = //do something
    return result;
}
public static int MyMethodForString(this List<int> list)
{
    int result = //do something
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Which constrain (`class` or `struct`) allow `Nullable<T>` to pass?

Comment: This do not address my comment. You say: *As there´s no type that is neither a class nor a struct*. So, given `Nullable<T>` type. Will it pass `class` constrain? Will it pass `struct` constrain? And, BTW, what do you mean by *`Nullable<T>`-constraint*? I am not aware of such thing.